# Asyncio , aiohttp , bs4

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was trying to get information of 80000 items with asyncio but when I run the code
"Server Disconnected" error. if someone can tell me what is wrong whit the code or what I have to add to solve this problem

```
async def get_page(session,url):
    async with session.get(url) as r:
       contenedor = requests.get(url).text
       soup = BeautifulSoup(await r.text(), "lxml")
       description_soup = soup.find(itemprop="description")
       text = description_soup.get_text().strip().replace("\r\n"," ")
       text = text.replace("DrivePart", "Drive Part")
       descripcion = text[:text.find("Part")]
       partnumber  = text[text.find("Part"):]
       compatibility = soup.find("span",{"class":"roboto_black10"})
       if " is compatible with " in contenedor:
           compa = compatibility.get_text().strip()
       else:
        compa = ""
       return [url,descripcion,partnumber,compa]

async def get_all(session, urls):
    tasks = []
    for url in urls:
        task = asyncio.create_task(get_page(session, url))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def main(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = await get_all(session,urls)
    return data

await main(url["url"].tolist())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code that I can see (other than you call fetching the same page twice, one with aiohttp and the other with requests).  I suspect the webserver doesn't like to be hammered with tons of http calls.  I would put a delay between each call, or talk to the website operator to allow lots of connections.  An alternative would be to check the http status code and put in a delay then retry logic only when resp.status != 200.  that would be the most robust solution.

Comment: Thanks @toppk :) I will try now with resp.status

Comment: I try adding delay and still the error :(

Comment: @EduardoHoJungParga does it error after the first call, or after a while?

Comment: after  a while, it's take like 2 min

Comment: @EduardoHoJungParga I think it is triggering a anti ddos trigger.  you may have to slow it down to one call for every 5-10 seconds.   Adding all the urls you want to queue file and removing urls you've already fetched from the queue file will allow you to not start over every invocation from scratch.  web scrapping is a tough business.  good luck!